# Solr Umlaut handling

Tags: solr

I am trying to do the following in Solr.
I would like to treat, for example, ü and ue as equivalent while searching. Similarly for the other umlauts. The user of the search API, should be able to search with either and still get the same results.  For example searching with `übersicht` and uebersicht should turn up the same results

I saw SnowballPorterFilterFactory with the German2 language attribute. The German2 attribute looks to be what I need, but I would like to use it without having to introduce Stemming.
Is this possible

Comment: You might want to start by testing the ICUFoldingFilter: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/filter-descriptions.html#icu-folding-filter  or the ICUNormalizer2 filter: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/filter-descriptions.html#icu-normalizer-2-filter - they do this according to unicode folding rules. However, I'm not sure if the folding rules match what you're after for German.

Comment: In German, it is most common to treat ä/ae, ö/oe, ü/ue and ß/ss as equivalent each (the plain ASCII character versions are used in cases where the special characters are not available, e.g. when using an English keyboard). The default GermanNormalizationFilter however treats ä/ae/a, ö/oe/o, ü/ue/u and ß/ss as equivalent each. The first 3 equivalences are weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
`<filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>` https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanNormalizationFilter.html

This works so:

- 'ß' is replaced by 'ss'
- 'ä', 'ö', 'ü' are replaced by 'a', 'o', 'u', respectively.
- 'ae' and 'oe' are replaced by 'a', and 'o', respectively.
- 'ue' is replaced by 'u', when not following a vowel or q.

Also you can use `<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>` with your own mapping file. https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_1_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/charfilter/MappingCharFilterFactory.html

Example of the mapping.txt:

"ü" => "ue"

"ä" => "ae"

Comment: The GermanNormalizationFilter contains the (in my case) unwanted mapping from ä/ae->a, ö/oe->o, ü/ue->u. Instead, the mapping should be ä->ae, ö->oe, ü->ue (mapping ß->ss is fine).

For example, if I search for "Uber" (the company), I don't expect to find the pretty frequent word "über".
How can this be achieved? A charfilter is not an option, as this happens before the filter chain. I would like this to happen as a replacement for the GermanNormalizationFilter. Is that possible?

Comment: Pardon the novice question, but where should this go? I've placed it in a schema.xml file and placed it in the core/conf folder, restarted solr and re-indexed, but the search didn't work. Must I configure something else somewhere?